# How to customize Sphinx doc images folder?

Tags: image, internationalization, python-sphinx

I'm working with Sphinx doc and I want to translate my documentation to other languages. I want to make images language dependent so screenshots in English will be in one folder and screenshots in German in other.

Currently Sphinx takes all images from /images folder. As I see in other stackoverflow questions it is impossible to modify image directive path with variable substitutions.

Is it possible to change default images folder by some CLI option or other way?

UPD. I use Sphinx 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [asked](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3216) this question in Sphinx github.
Takeshi Komiya gave answer which solved my problem.
He suggests to use [figure_language_filename](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-figure_language_filename) option. I tried and it works. I can flexibly set path to image folders.
Note: figure_language_filename option is available since Sphinx 1.4.

Comment: I would be interested to see how you have configured it. Can you please share an example here?

Comment: @Sach It was a long time ago so no guarantees it still works. My configuration is here 
https://github.com/NtsDK/larpwriter-toolkit-nims-translations/blob/630b2137dfaaa63d0ad903a0856c169ad3787710/nims/en/doc/conf.py#L72

Comment: Thanks @NtsDK. I used the same setting in conf.py and when does the new image is generated? I ran `make gettext` and then updated my .po files using `sphinx-intl update -p build/gettext -l ja`. I don't see any image files generated for that language.